# Not assignable with null. TS

Tags: angular, typescript, null

(property) State.editedIngredient: Ingredient
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Ingredient'.ts(2322)
shopping-list.reducer.ts(6, 3): The expected type comes from property 'editedIngredient' which is declared here on type 'State'

****editedIngredient: null****

This is my small problem, dont know how to fix it.

```
export interface State {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
  editedIngredient: Ingredient;
  editedIngredientIndex: number;
}

export interface AppState {
  shoppingList: State;
}

const initialState: State = {
  ingredients: [new Ingredient('Apples', 5), new Ingredient('Tomatoes', 4)],
  editedIngredient: null,
  editedIngredientIndex: -1,
};
```

```
export class Ingredient {
  constructor(public name: string, public amount: number) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `editedIngredient` nullable :

```
export interface State {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
  editedIngredient: Ingredient | null;
  editedIngredientIndex: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is telling you that you cannot set this property to null. That's because you've told typescript that `editedIngredient` must always be `Ingredient`.

What you want to do is tell typescript that it could be an `Ingredient` or it could be `null`. You can do this with the union operator `|` like so:

```
export interface State {
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
  editedIngredient: Ingredient | null;
  editedIngredientIndex: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `editedIngredient: <Ingredient>{}` to assign an empty object of type `Ingredient` instead of null since your interface declaration is `editedIngredient: Ingredient;` if you really need to assign `null` instead if empty object then declare it as `editedIngredient: Ingredient | null;`